# jQuery dataTables responsive recalc Issue

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, datatables-1.10

I am using v1.10.6, when I changed the display for a datatable Container, all rows become collapsed. I tried to use:

```js
oTable.responsive.recalc();
```

and:

```js
oTable.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

Also I tried:

```js
$($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().responsive.recalc();
```

but it's removing the responsive functionality of the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your problem was easy to reproduce. A basic `responsive: true` initialisation does in fact collapse the rows when the table is shrinked, but does not expand the rows when the table is enlarged, and seems not to work at all if you make the table larger than its original size.

But setting `autoWidth: false` seems to do the trick :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    autoWidth: false, //<---
    responsive : true
});

window.onresize = function() {
    table.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
}
```

Now it seems to work as it supposed to do.
Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/g0vhvcp7/**